# Eclipse Che: Can't find che.env

Tags: eclipse-che

I'm trying to enable GitHub oAuth in Eclipse Che. The [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/configuration/index.html#oauth) calls for modification of `che.env`.

Further, [the docs say](http://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/configuration/index.html):

> Configuration is handled by modifying che.env placed in the host
>   folder volume mounted to :/data. This configuration file is generated
>   during the che init phase.

I run Eclipse Che in a docker container as follows:

```
mkdir /home/<USERNAME>/che
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
            --name che \
            --rm \
            -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
            -v /home/<USERNAME>/che:/data \
            eclipse/che-server:5.0.0-latest
```

(Ref: http://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/docker/index.html)

I enter the container and search for che.env:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash
find /data -name 'che.env'
```

Nothing is returned, thus the file `che.env` doesn't exist in `/data`.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

As per your docker run command, host folder mounted to volume `:/data` is  `/home/<USERNAME>/che` so your `che.env` file must exist at path -
 `/home/<USERNAME>/che/che.env`

**Update -** Image used to run eclipse che is different in `docker run` command. `eclipse/che` image is required for running eclipse che. Complete command -

```
docker run -it --rm -v /che-data:/data -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock eclipse/che:5.17.0 start
```

Comment: As you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/sm8Krr1.jpg) and [here](https://i.imgur.com/kqp53Si.jpg), that is not the case.

Comment: @matthiash [this](https://i.imgur.com/kqp53Si.jpg) screenshot is your host machine or container ? `che.env` file will get stored in host machine

Comment: The screenshot is from my host machine. Have you tried replicating the issue, and if so, how does it look at your side?

Comment: @matthiash I have similar environment. In my case, host folder which is mounted to `:/data` is /che-data/ and `che.env` file is present in this directory. The folders that you showed in screenshot, is present in workspace data in host machine and `/data/ ` folder in container.

Comment: Could you give me the exact commands you use to 1) start the container and 2) identify the `che.env` file. I seem to need some spoon feeding here :)

Comment: The command that I used for starting the container - `docker run -it --rm -v /che-data:/data     -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock     eclipse/che:5.17.0 start`. Regarding identifying `che.env` file, as you can see in command, my host folder is che-data and `che.env` file gets created inside this.

Comment: I ran your command, and now the che.env file gets created. I notice that you run another image than me, I run `eclipse/che-server`, while you run `eclipse/che` (and the `start` command). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's in /home//che folder. Make sure you restart Che after making changes to the file